# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' when creating object

Tags: python, django, model

I'm trying to read from a CSV file and create an object in Django (1.9, Py 3.5) but I'm getting this error, no matter what I change the field to

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

And the line is:

> other                         = row['Other']

```
site = Site.objects.create(consolidated_financials      = row['Consolidated financials'],
                                  type                          = Type.objects.get_or_create(name=row['Type'])[0],
                                  tier1_business                = Business.objects.get_or_create(tier=1, name=row['Tier-1 business'])[0],
                                  tier2_business                = Business.objects.get_or_create(tier=2, name=row['Tier-2 business'])[0],
                                  tier3_business                = Business.objects.get_or_create(tier=2, name=row['Tier-3 business'])[0],
                                  site_name                     = row['Site Name'],
                                  site_id                       = row['Site ID'],
                                  region                        = Region.objects.get_or_create(name=row['Region'])[0],
                                  country                       = Country.objects.get_or_create(name=row['Country'], region=Region.objects.get_or_create(name=row['Region'])[0])[0],
                                  city                          = City.objects.get_or_create(name=row['City'], country=Country.objects.get_or_create(name=row['Country'], region=Region.objects.get_or_create(name=row['Region'])[0])[0])[0],
                                  site_type                     = SiteType.objects.get_or_create(name=row['Type of site?'])[0],
                                  remote_site                   = row['Remote site?'],
                                  finance_manager_name          = row['Finance Manager Name'],
                                  finance_manager_sso           = row['Finance Manager SSO'],
                                  quarter                       = row['Quarter'],
                                  revenue                       = row['Revenue'],
                                  supply_chain_manager_name     = row['Supply Chain Manager Name'],
                                  supply_chain_manager_sso      = row['Supply Chain Manager SSO'], 
                                  product_lines                 = row['Product Lines'],
                                  manufacturing_processes       = row['Manufacturing Processes'],
                                  factory_utilization           = row['Factory Utilization'],
                                  fte                           = row['FTE'],
                                  hourly                        = row['Hourly'],
                                  salaried                      = row['Salaried'],
                                  other                         = row['Other']
                                  )
```

The Site model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
"""
Model for a site entry
@author: Leonardo Pessoa
@since: 05/09/2016 
"""
from decimal import Decimal

consolidated_financials     = models.BooleanField()
type                        = models.ForeignKey(Type)
tier1_business              = models.ForeignKey(Business, limit_choices_to = {'tier': 1}, related_name='%(class)s_tier1')
tier2_business              = models.ForeignKey(Business, limit_choices_to = {'tier': 2}, related_name='%(class)s_tier2')
tier3_business              = models.ForeignKey(Business, limit_choices_to = {'tier': 3}, related_name='%(class)s_tier3')
site_name                   = models.CharField(max_length = 150, unique=True)
site_id                     = models.IntegerField()
region                      = models.ForeignKey(Region)
country                     = models.ForeignKey(Country)
city                        = models.ForeignKey(City)
site_type                   = models.ForeignKey(SiteType)
remote_site                 = models.BooleanField()
finance_manager_name        = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
finance_manager_sso         = models.IntegerField()
quarter                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default=Decimal('0.0'))
revenue                     = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default=Decimal('0.0'))
supply_chain_manager_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default='')
supply_chain_manager_sso    = models.IntegerField(default=000000000)
product_lines               = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default='')
manufacturing_processes     = models.TextField(max_length = 500, default='')
factory_utilization         = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2, default=Decimal('0.0'))
fte                         = models.IntegerField()
hourly                      = models.IntegerField()
salaried                    = models.IntegerField()
other                       = models.TextField(max_length = 500, default='')
ges_id                      = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
latitude                    = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places=7, default=Decimal('0.0'))
longitude                   = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places=7, default=Decimal('0.0'))
```

The row:

```
row 
{'City': 'xxxxxxx',
 'Consolidated financials': 'True',
 'Country': 'Argentina (AR)',
 'FTE': '',
 'Factory Utilization': '',
 'Finance Manager Name': '',
 'Finance Manager SSO': '',
 'Hourly': '',
 'Manufacturing Processes': '',
 'Other': '',
 'Product Lines': '',
 'Quarter': '',
 'Region': 'Latin America',
 'Remote site?': 'True',
 'Revenue': '',
 'Salaried': '',
 'Site ID': '12312',
 'Site Name': 'xxxxxxxxx',
 'Supply Chain Manager Name': '',
 'Supply Chain Manager SSO': '',
 'Tier-1 business': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
 'Tier-2 business': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'Tier-3 business': 'Latin America',
 'Type': 'xxxxxx xxxxx',
 'Type of site?': 'Other'}
```

I know the code has a lot of room for performance optimization but I just want to prove the functionality first.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert other to an int.  If it is usually a string representing a number you can do `int(other)`, but if it is empty string, you need to replace it with 0 probably

Comment: @joelgoldstick i just added the model for reference. It takes text.

Comment: But somehow it is getting an empty string.  Look at your csv file for the line in question

Comment: @joelgoldstick it is, it's empty. Can't I have an empty string there?

Comment: Yes, and you declare it as text.  So, can you please show the complete traceback, and the code that it refers to

Comment: Wanted to understand why so many down votes. Would anybody mind to elaborate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Site` model is expecting `other` to be an `int` (does the model have `other = IntegerField` or similar?), and you're providing an empty string. The easiest fix is to change `row['Other']` to `row['Other'] or 0`

If you know that you're going to get non-numeric values as a general rule, then you could add basic logic to test for non-digits, or update your IntegerField to something which can accept text. [A list of valid Django fields can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/).

```
# An example of conditional logic to test for a non-number and use 0 if so
other = row['Other'] if row['Other'] and row['Other'].isdigit() else 0
```

---

### Edit

Looking at your model, the issue is probably not with the Other field, but there are typing problems nevertheless. For example `Supply Chain Manager SSO` is supposed to be an int, but you are definitely passing a `''`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added the model for reference, it's a TextField.

Comment: Right on the spot! The problem was all about the different types in my CSV and expected field. It was hard to read that by the error as that line specifically didn't have a problem. Thank you so much!